# Why is this Cypress Intercept on query and fixture mock throwing an invalid RouteMatcher error?

Tags: cypress

I moved from Cypress 6.$.$ to 7.7.0 and now my intercept started to fail with

```
An invalid RouteMatcher was supplied to cy.intercept(). An unknown RouteMatcher property was passed: qs
```

```js
  cy.intercept({
        pathname: '/api/cms-users/',
        qs: {
          all: true,
          limit: 10,
          order: 'first_name',
          start: 0
        }
      }, {fixture: 'test-data/users/users-default-response-test-data.json'}
    );
```

I've made several attempts to fix it, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#7-0-0? They _"introduced several breaking changes to cy.intercept()"_ you should be aware of when trying to upgrade. Or you can just look at the current [RouteMatcher docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher) to see what properties _are_ known.

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe suggested, a quick read of the docs helped. Changing the `qs` to `query` and turning the query values into strings did the job.

```
 cy.intercept({
        pathname: '/api/cms-users/',
        query: {
          all: 'true',
          limit: '10',
          order: 'first_name',
          start: '0'
        }
      }, {fixture: 'test-data/users/users-default-response-test-data.json'}
    );
```